# Resize NSimage but loses exif data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Please help

Currently looking to create a new NSImage by resizing an original and then send it over to a web service along with its original EXIF data. I can resize the image no problem but the EXIF data is not present. The call to `representationUsingType` takes in the propertiesDict which is correct as per the Apple Docs :)

Can someone please point me in the correct dirrection please, here is my current implementation:

```
NSData *imageData = [resizedImage TIFFRepresentation]; //resized image is a my resized NSImage

NSBitmapImageRep * image = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithData:imageData]; //NEED NSBitmapImageRepObject


NSMutableDictionary * propertiesDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[propertiesDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:self.imageSizeSlider.floatValue] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
[propertiesDict setObject:metaDataDict forKey:NSImageEXIFData];

NSData * shrunkImage = [image representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:propertiesDict];
```

If i writeToFile the shrunkImage object I get the image but with only the color profile in the exif? :( 
The metaDataDict object has all the exif in I need and can be NSLogged to show that.

Any help much appreciated.
Regards,
Lee

Answer (score -2):

You haven't shrunk the image, you've made a new image that's smaller than the original.  Your new image has only the metadata that you give  it.

Read the docs on NSImage and NSImageRep, and look  up how to get and set EXIF data.

Comment: OK, i have revised my question for it to state that I have created a smaller version of the original. Your comment of " Your new image has only the metadata that you give it." is useless, if you read the code and was more practical with your answer you will see I mention I have the original EXIF and apply this correctly to my smaller NSImage as per the docs of NSImage.